# How to add sequencer on STM32WL?

Tags: stm32, c, lora

I am working with 3 STM32WL55JC modules. 1 used as receiver and the other 2 as transmitters.

The code:

```c
UTIL_SEQ_RegTask((1 << CFG_SEQ_Task_Sensor_Process), 0, Sensor_Process);
```

I want to add another task which needs to work as endless loop. The task is accelerometer and it works at 20 Hz.

```c
UTIL_TIMER_Create(&accelMovementTimer,0xFFFFFFFF,UTIL_TIMER_PERIODIC,movement_Process,NULL);
UTIL_TIMER_SetPeriod(&accelMovementTimer,10); //10ms
UTIL_TIMER_Start(&accelMovementTimer);
```

I can get this task to work with a timer but I want to use a sequencer. So I added this in *utilities_def.h*:

```c
typedef enum
{
  CFG_SEQ_Task_Sensor_Process,
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CFG_SEQ_Task_Id_t */
  CFG_SEQ_Task_movement_Process,
 
  /* USER CODE END CFG_SEQ_Task_Id_t */
  CFG_SEQ_Task_NBR
} CFG_SEQ_Task_Id_t;
```

And this line in *subghz_phy_app.c*:

```c
UTIL_SEQ_RegTask((1 << CFG_SEQ_Task_movement_Process), 0, movement_Process);
```

But it doesn't work.

My question is, how can I add this task properly?

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your task first :

- `UTIL_SEQ_RegTask(1<<YOUR_TASK_ID, YOUR_TASK_FLAGS, TASK);`
  Then you need to set a priority for your task :
- `UTIL_SEQ_SetTask(1<<YOUR_TASK_ID,YOUR_TASK_PRIORITY);`